# Infinite Boolean Matrix

Tags: code-golf

It's geeky to see a Boolean Matrix animation, but a live one would be better. Echoing only `1`s and `0`s create a program that creates an infinite loop of integer matrix.

- `1`s and `0`s are randomly echoed like an error.
- [image: Illustaration]

Comment: Please clarify. First, what does "like an error" mean? Second, what counts as "predefined functions to randomise the output", and what source of randomness _are_ we allowed to use?

Comment: I think I just don't have to mention that, "predefined functions to randomise the output", sorry for that...

Comment: "Using only 1s and 0s create a program ..." ... that means binary coding ...

Comment: :D Thanks for that I didn't noticed, I'm glad you commented

Comment: @Daniel, I suggest that you read some questions on this site, read some answers, and write some answers of your own. When you understand better what makes a good question, try to rewrite this one.

Comment: @ugoren I'm probably did wrote a bad question, I suppose... Should I leave this question idle or delete it?

Comment: @Daniel, If you think you can fix it with a bit of work, do so and ask to reopen. If not, delete and try again when you're ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

## PHP, <s>28</s> 22

```
for(;;)echo rand(0,1);
```

---

For a better view:

```
<div style="width:800px;margin:0 auto;background-color:black;color:green;">
    <?php for(;;)echo rand(0,1); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: i wonder if you can use `for(;;)` instead of `while(true)`

Comment: Sure, you're right! Edited :) I also removed brackets.

Answer (score 2):

#### Delphi XE3  (<strike>30</strike> 28)

```
while 0<1do write(Random(2))
```

Comment: I don't know Delphi, but can you use `0<1` to replace `true`?

Comment: Can't you use `while 1` in delphi?

Comment: @user689 Nope, it requires a boolean expression.

Answer (score 0):

### TI-BASIC, 46

A classic, in my opinion.

```
"101010101010101":While 1:Disp Ans,"0"+Ans:End
```

Comment: doesn't seem very random. It's mostly zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, 24

```
print-+-(rand>.5)while+1
```

Answer (score 0):

**C# 112** - **109 Thanks @masterX244**

```
using System;namespace N{class P{static void Main(string[]a){for(;;)Console.Write(new Random().Next(0,2));}}}
```

Without namespace, class name...

**45**

```
for(;;)Console.Write(new Random().Next(0,2));
```

**Uncompressed**

```
using System;namespace N{class P{
        static void Main(string[] a) {
            for (;;)
                Console.Write(new Random().Next(0, 2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for(;;) is shorter btw